# What is the first and last number in the points attribute for an svg polygon?

Tags: svg, polygons

I'm trying to understand what the first and last number value in points attribute represent, but MDN doesn't seem to explain this, it actually says there needs to be two numbers, however I keep seeing this first and last pattern. I keep noticing that there are pairs of numbers, the values that represent the x and y axis of the point, however their is just a single number that isn't a pair at the beginning and end?

```
<svg height="210" width="500">
   <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198">//what does first and last number mean?
   <style="fill:lime;stroke:purple;stroke-width:5;fill-rule:evenodd;" />
</svg>
```

Comment: the points are the polygon vertices. What else would they be?

Answer (score 6):

You are misinterpreting the numbers and their separators.

In a `points` value like the following:

```
100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198
```

The X and Y coordinates are separated by a comma, and the **pairs** are separated by a space (but using a comma is also allowed here).

So there are five X,Y coordinate pairs: (100,10) (40,198) (190,78) (10,78) and (160,198)